# Parameterized Python SQLite3 query is returning the first parameter

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, select, parameterized-query

I'm trying to make a query to a SQLite database from a python script. However, whenever I use parameterization it just returns the first parameter, which is `column2`. The desired result is for it to return the value held in `column2` on the row where `column1` is equal to `row1`.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('path/to/database')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT ? from table WHERE column1 = ? ;', ("column2","row1"))
result = c.fetchone()[0]
print(result)
```

It prints

```
>>column2
```

Whenever I run this using concatenated strings, it works fine.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('path/to/database')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT ' + column2 + ' from table WHERE column1 = ' + row1 + ';')
result = c.fetchone()[0]
print(result)
```

And it prints:

```
>>desired data
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaves as designed.

The mechanism that parameterized queries provide is meant to pass literal values to the query, not meta information such as column names.

One thing to keep in mind is that the database must be able to *parse* the parameterized query string without having the parameter at hand: obviously, a column name cannot be used as parameter under such assumption.

For your use case, the only possible solution is to concatenate the column name into the query string, as shown in your second example. If the parameter comes from outside your code, be sure to properly validate it before that (for example, by checking it against a fixed list of values).